# Cursor coding for wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, cursor

I have the following code which I would like to implement in my Wordpress site, in order to have a customized mouse pointer.

where would I insert this code? Into the index.php file itself? Or into a separate text file?

Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {

            //create img elements having pointer.png in their src 
            pointer = $('<img>').attr({'src':'pointer.png'});

            //and append them to document
            $(document.body).append(pointer); 

            //show them at mouse position & fade out slowly
            pointer.css({
                    'position':'absolute',
                    top: e.pageY +2 ,    //offsets
                    left: e.pageX +2   //offsets
                }).fadeOut(1500);   
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `cursor` rule in CSS. If you can modify the global CSS somewhere, just add `cursor: url(/path/to/cursor.png);` to `html` or `body`.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  Would this not just change the cursor image from the normal "arrow" to the image I would like used?  I would like it to be a "cursor trail" - for lack of a better word..

Comment: If you want a cursor trail, you'd need to use Javascript, yes. However, a lot of people frown upon cursor trails, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: thank you. I have tried advising my client against it, however he insists up on it. I'm currently using the plugin: CursorTrails, but it does not display the trail the way he would like.so I could just insert this code into the "head" section of the index.php page then?

Comment: Yes, the best place for a Javascript block would be inside the `<head>` tag. Partially offtopic: You should submit the story about the insisting client on [Clients from Hell](http://clientsfromhell.net/).

Comment: I dont see a <head> tag in either the index.php file or the page.php file?

Comment: Can you provide a pastebin? (I don't use Wordpress, so I don't know what it would look like)

Comment: sure, http://pastebin.com/h1RmYVgU        thank you for the link to clientsFromHell :-)

Comment: `<?php get_header(); ?>` will probably lead you to the `head`. You could try to find it by finding the function and seeing what it does. [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript) it says that the `head` is located in `header.php`. I hope that solves your problem. c:

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17412/discussion-between-user1426583-and-darkwater)

Comment: thank you very much. I see that there is a place where script is inserted - perhaps underneath line 21? pastebin.com/epD4fps7

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would put this `<head><script>HERE</script></head>` of the page you want it to be on.  Make sure you have imported jquery first though.

Comment: thank you for that.  I would like this cursor to appear this way in all my pages, would I need to add the code into the "head" of every page?

Comment: The trail will appear on every page that has the script in it, so yes.